# No routes matched location in - react-router nested routes

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Im trying to get this react-router working and i'm having some trouble. I have a route that works just fine for either landingpage or app. Inside the app im trying to do another `Routes` like the following:

```
<div className="bet-app">
            </Sidebar>
            <div className="app-wrapper">
                <Routes>
                    <Route path='/app/profile' element={<Profile />} />

                    <Route path='/app/achievments' element={<Achievments />} />
                </Routes>
            </div>
        </div>
```

But this gets the error: `utils.ts:900 No routes matched location "/app/profile"

Sidebar should be visible on both profile and achievments but depending on route toggle those 2.

What am i doing wrong here?